# Changing background color of a block link on hovering

Tags: html, css, hover, background-color

I am creating a few links on my web page and I wanted to have an effect, like a change in the background or the size of the text seeming to grow up, whenever I hover over those links. The links are displayed like `blocks`.

---

*html part*

```
<div>
   <a class="leftimagelinks" href="#">Submit a paper</a><br>
   <a class="leftimagelinks" href="#">Get the brochure</a><br>
   <a class="leftimagelinks" href="#">Housing and travel</a>
</div>
```

*css part*

```
.leftimagelinks {
margin: auto;
display: block;
width: 190px;
height: 25px;
border-radius: 8px;
text-align: center;
padding: 4px;
color: yellow;
background-color: black;
background-color: #32CD32;
}

.leftimagelinks a:hover{
background-color: red;
}
```

---

But even after the above whenever I hover over the links, nothing changes. Whats the mistake here ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The CSS selector `.leftimageslinks a:hover` tries to select a link inside '.leftimageslinks'. Instead, try this:

```
.leftimagelinks:hover{
  background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BGJJn/

Comment: You can also use `a.leftimagelinks:hover`to make sure that the hover only applies to a-tags containing the class leftimagelinks.

Comment: You can, but it's advised against unless really needed. See this article: http://csswizardry.com/2012/11/code-smells-in-css/

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
.leftimagelinks:hover
```

You are using wrong selector.